# Creating a kernel for a 2D gaussian process regressor in sk learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, gaussian-process

I am trying to use a Gaussian Process regression model for a Bayesian optimization piece. The GP model is to approximate my objective function. It has two inputs (variables) (x, y) which return a single output z. I am struggling to know which kernel / which combination of kernels to use for the GP model. I have tried a product and sum of two SE kernels (RBF + RBF and RBF x RBF) and so far the predictions are not that great. I have used a 81 training points (pairs of x,y) and resultant z values to train the model. I have also included an image of the 3D data below if that helps, and the code. Really I just need some help to understand which kernels to use / how to build a custom one to fit my data. Any help would be massively appreciated.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
    x_train = np.array(list_of_pairs)
    y_train = training_data['result'].to_list()
    
    kernel = gp.kernels.RBF(length_scale=0.00000000005, length_scale_bounds=(0.000001, 100000)) * gp.kernels.RBF(length_scale=0.00000000005, length_scale_bounds=(0.000001, 100000)) 
    model = gp.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel = kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=4)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train)
    
    test_sample = [[0.1,57]]
    test_sample = np.array(test_sample)
    yhat, covar = model.predict(test_sample, return_std=True)
    print(yhat, covar)
    print(model.kernel_.get_params())
```

below is a screenshot of some output errors which I also could use some help understanding.[image]

Comment: Please note, that Stack Overflow discourages **screenshot** which contains just a **text**. Instead, copy paste that text directly into the question post.

Comment: I would suggest the following actions which I think will get you closer to solving your problem. 1. [Standarize](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) your data. GP is very sensitive to different scales. 2. Use just one generic kernel for now such as RBF. If these two steps run without errors and give ballpark results then you can add complexity in your model perhaps by tuning the hyperparameters or by using more complicated kernels.